# React.js: Resize table generated by React-Google-Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization

I am using React-Google-Chart to visualize the data that I have in my component. However, the chart itself, does not get larger visually but as a element..

Let me explain:

```
<div className="container">
            <Chart
                chartType="Table"
                width="100%"
                height="400%"
                data={this.mapArray()}
                options={this.state.options}
            />
</div>
```

My option state:

```
    options : {
        title: "Company Performance",
        curveType: "function",
        legend: { position: "bottom" },
        pageSize: 50
    },
```

Currently I have the width as `100%`. Now if I set the width to `1000%`, the actual visual width does not get any wider. However, if I inspect the CSS elements, it showed that the `div` is taking out 10 times spaces as it used to. However, it is not what i wanted. I tried to play with the default CSS provided by google but it does not get any larger. Apparently, it is the max size it can get,but it is still really smaller compare to the background

What I wanted to do : I want to make the chart larger visually.  Both chart itself and the field.

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Curious if you found an answer to this. I am using react-google-charts as well and experiencing similar issue. I placed the component inside a <div> and set the dimensions on that but it does not change. I change the dimensions of the component it self and it does not change. takes up 100% of the screen it just does not fit the the container fully. Also, it is no responsive at all.